# Sanitizing inputs by updating locals() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

My ultimate goal is an efficient way to convert all my numeric inputs to numpy arrays and make sure they have the correct shapes.

Here is the behavior I was considering:

```
def test_func(a, b):
    for item in locals():
        new_val = ... # code to sanitize the input 
                      #      (convert to numpy array, reshape, etc.)
        locals().update({item:new_val})
```

The issue, of course, is that you can't update locals in Python 3.X. So I guess my question can be summarized as follows:

- How do you efficiently sanitize your numeric inputs (converting to numpy arrays/reshaping) while minimizing boilerplate code?

Comment: By "inputs", do you mean local variables or arguments of functions?

Comment: Um, why not just `for item in (a, b):`...? I don't understand why you are trying to use `locals` here.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want all the arguments of a function converted to `np.array`, it is quite helpful to use a decorator.

```
import numpy as np


def np_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # silently convert arguments to np.array
        new_args = [np.array(x) for x in args]
        new_kwargs = {k: np.array(v) for k,v in kwargs.items()}

        # actual execution when called
        func(*new_args, **new_kwargs)

    return wrapper


@np_decorator
def test_func(a, b):
    print(type(a), type(b))


test_func([2], [5])
# <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Though I do think sometimes you don't need to convert all the arguments. You may adjust the decorator to fit your need. E.g. convert `*args` only but leaves `**kwargs` untouched.

Comment: A bit dangerous if I have the signature: `def f(a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray, c: List[float], d: int)`

Comment: @FHTMitchell True! a) Keep `d` in kwargs, b) try catch with `np.scalar`, or c) just don't try to automate this if arguments are complicated. Your methods is clearer if explicit specification is required anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. If you're accepting so many arguments that the boilerplate is large, you're doing it wrong.

You do

```
def sanitize(x):
    # do sanitation things
    return new_x

def test_func(a, b):
    a = santize(a)
    b = santize(b)
```